# Spanish Character cant be seen properly ios

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

```
NSString *urlString = GET_EVENTLIST_URL_STRING;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if (!url)
    {
        NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not create URL from string %@", GET_EVENTLIST_URL_STRING];
        [self.delegate didGetEventListInCorrect:reason];
        return;
    }

    // Create a mutable request because we will append data to it.
    theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 30.0];

    // Set the HTTP method of the request to POST
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];




    if (!theRequest)
    {
        NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not create URL request from string %@", GET_EVENTLIST_URL_STRING];
        [self.delegate didGetEventListInCorrect:reason];
        return;
    }
    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

=====
Hi All,
I have this code and  this is my string "Evento Público" but I see in output as " Ãºblico " .I have used NSUTF8StringEncoding also but i couldnt manage this?Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the server transmits its data using UTF8 encoding? Try Charles Proxy for debugging all server based communication.

Comment: Yes, because I dont have any problem for other text..?